# Unable to match path using ui routing in angularjs v1.6

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How can I get the ui router in angular to resolve to the correct state?

I'm trying to run an angular application inside a subdirectory of my site but can't get the app.route.js to properly route the request. I set the "otherwise" directive to "dang" so that it's obvious to me if it misses.

I'm trying to reach the application at a URL like:
`example.us/search`

I'm landing at the proper directory in the url because I get routed to `example.us/search/#!/dang`

The file location for the content (ie `app/partials/search.html`) is a subfolder of the search folder, which is inside the root folder.

```
angular.module('example.usApp')
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('dang');
    $stateProvider
         .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/search.html',
            controller: 'searchController',
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', 
                        files: [
                            'app/services/searchService.js',
                            'app/controllers/searchController.js',
                            'css/home.css'
                        ]
                    });
                }]
            }
        })...
```

EDIT:
The files[] array above does not get loaded obviously because the url doesn't match. I'm having hard time loading any change because the browser thinks I'm trying to angular route and is not reloading the page at the URL I specify. When I type a change in the url bar and hit enter the URL is rewritten without making a request to the server.

EDIT2:
In answer to a question, yes oclazyload.js is loaded. From the developer tools you can see that all of the following are loaded in this order:

```
search/
bootstrap.min.css
style.css
angular.min.js
angular-ui-router.min.js
angular-local-storage.min.js
ocLazyLoad.min.js
angular-cookies.min.js
jquery.easing.1.3.js
angular-payments.min.js
app.js
app.constants.js
LoginService.js
app.route.js
bootstrap.min.js
app.constants.js
LoginService.js
app.route.js
bootstrap.min.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This state is abstract so you will never hit it. I am assuming your main single page is Index.html right? If so change to this:

```
angular.module('example.usApp')
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('dang');
    $stateProvider
         .state('home', {
            url: '/search',
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/search.html',
            controller: 'searchController',
            resolve: {
                deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                        insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', 
                        files: [
                            'app/services/HomeService.js',
                            'app/controllers/HomeMainController.js',
                            'css/home.css'
                        ]
                    });
                }]
            }
        })...
```

The url should be `example.us/#/search`.

Comment: After changing I still get directed to `example.us/search/#!/dang`. There's no change. What do you mean when you say the state is abstract?

Comment: You have abstract: true when you define the state. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#abstract-states

Comment: Where to do you put reference to angularjs: <script src=.....></script> .Index.html right

Comment: Yes, correct, and all the scripts and css files are being called according to the developer console except the ones called inside of the files array given above.

Comment: Can you try without search: example.us

Comment: Example.us is outside of angular. The index.html file is inside the folder located at example.us/search. The app folder is located at example.us/search/app. The app.route.js is being hit because it's also redirecting to example.us/search/#!/dang.

Comment: Did you  load the lazyload Module when you create the module: "oc.lazyLoad"

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: I had to do with the fact I didn't know what abstract meant in ui router. :)